# How to prevent visual studio from hiding files and folders in gitignored?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have some temp files and folders in my cmake project directory, I added them into gitignored, and them disappear from visual studio's solution explorer. In fact sometimes I need to edit them, but since them hidden, I have to go back to the windows explorer to open them.

I wonder how can I make them shown, or better, shown in grey color like in vscode?

I have navigated the setting panel but don't known which box to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

In the Preferences > settings, search "use ignore files" and unchecked it. After this your .gitignore files are visible in VS code.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but actually I mean in visual studio rather than visual studio code.

Comment: Did you check in the folder view ? In Home screen GUI, navigate to: Solution explorer - Folder View (will give you more files), top icons: select “Show All Files”. You will get all files displayed including .gitignore’ed and the ignored will have a red indicator on the left.